# Minimizing the Mahalanobis distance

Tags: optimization, quadratics, quadratic-forms, covariance, mahalanobis-distance

**Definitions**

Consider the following optimization problem
\begin{equation*}\arg \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \lVert y-x\rVert_{P}^2\end{equation*}
where $y,P$ are given parameters and
\begin{equation*}
\lVert y-x\rVert_{P}^2 \triangleq (y-x)'P(y-x)
\end{equation*}
assume that $P$ is a regular covariance matrix, that is  $P$ is symmetric and strictly positive definite ($P=P', P>0$).

**Question**

Under the previous assumption $P=P', P>0$, is it true that
\begin{equation*}\arg \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \lVert y-x\rVert_{P}^2=
\arg \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \lVert y-x\rVert^2
\end{equation*}?

**Observation**

In the simple case $2\times 2$, with the additional hypothesis that $P$ is diagonal, the equality seems to be true. Indeed, by denoting
\begin{equation*}
y=\left[\begin{array}{c}
y_1 \\
y_2
\end{array}\right]
\qquad
x=\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{array}\right]
\qquad
P=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
P_{11} & 0\\
0 & P_{22}
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
follows
\begin{equation*}
\lVert y-x\rVert_P^2= P_{11} (y_1-x_1)^2 + P_{22} (y_2-x_2)^2
\end{equation*}
now, due to the sum sign the objective is to jointly minimize $P_{11} (y_1-x_1)^2$ and $P_{22} (y_2-x_2)^2$. These are two decoupled problems, so they can be treated separately, that is we are searching for
\begin{equation*}
\arg\min_{x_i \in \mathbb{R}} P_{ii} (y_i - x_i)^2 \qquad i=1,2
\end{equation*}
now, since $P_{ii}$ is just a positive scaling factor, holds
\begin{equation*}
\arg\min_{x_i \in \mathbb{R}} P_{ii} (y_i - x_i)^2= 
\arg\min_{x_i \in \mathbb{R}} (y_i - x_i)^2
 \qquad i=1,2
\end{equation*}
and so rolling back to the original problem
\begin{equation*}\arg \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \lVert y-x\rVert_{P}^2=
\arg \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \lVert y-x\rVert^2
\end{equation*}

**Remark**

I've proved that the equality holds in the diagonal $2\times2$ case. The extension to the diagonal $n\times n$ case is identical. My difficulty is that I'm not sure how to treat the non-diagonal case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nabla_x \left( \|y - x\|^2_P \right) = 2 P (y-x) = 0$, so we have $x = y$,

$$y = \arg\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \,\|y - x\|^2_P$$

$\nabla_x \left( \|y-x\|^2 \right) = 2(y-x) = 0$, so we have $x = y$,

$$y = \arg \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \, \|y-x\|^2$$